# Incomplete \iftrue; error

Tags: conditionals

I use different if cases to put together a name. It works in the case were all of the if cases are false and in case the last one is true. If the first one is true I get the error `Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 22.` I don't really know what is wrong.

**Edit:** I tried adding a conditional for vonname, but it does not seem to work... It says that the command `\@name` is undefined. I changed the code below accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Name display:
% Include vonname:
\newif\if@displayvon
%\DeclareOption{vonname=true}{\@displayvontrue}
% Displaystyles:
\newif\if@lastfirstvonname
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=lastfirstvon}{\@lastfirstvonnametrue}
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=lastfirst}{\@lastfirstvonnametrue}
\newif\if@vonlastfirstname
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=vonlastfirst}{\@vonlastfirstnametrue}


%\let\if@lastfirstvonname\iftrue

\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vonname}[1]{\def\@vonname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
%\newcommand{\@name}{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
\if@lastfirstvonname
    \if@displayvon
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}
    \else
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
\else
    \if@vonlastfirstname
        \if@displayvon
            \def\@name{\@vonname\ \@lastname,\ \@firstname}
        \else
            \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
    \else
        \if@displayvon
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
        \else
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@lastname}
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\makeatother

\firstname{First}
\vonname{Von}
\lastname{Last}

\begin{document}
hello, my name is \par
\makeatletter
\@name
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you do `\let\if@lastfirstvonname\iffalse` there is no point in having  `\newif\if@lastfirstvonname` as that is basically all it does. You can delete  `\let\if@lastfirstvonname\iffalse` (as newif has set it false already, if you want to set it true, do not use `\let` use `\@lastfirstvonnametrue`

Comment: Don't modify a question if doing so invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using your `\if`...`\else` code indentation with your closing `\fi` as well. This should then make it clear where a conditional `\if`...`\else`...`\fi` structure starts and ends.

Here's a visual of the structures:

```
\if@lastfirstvonname % <--------------------------------------------------IF---\
  \if@displayvon % <------------------------------------IF---\                  |
    \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}%          |                 |
  \else % <---------------------------------------------ELSE--|                 |
    \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}%                     |                 |
  \fi % <-----------------------------------------------FI---/                  |
\else % <-----------------------------------------------------------------ELSE--|
  \if@vonlastfirstname % <---------------------------------------IF---\         |
    \if@displayvon % <----------------------------------IF---\         |        |
      \def\@name{\@vonname\ \@lastname,\ \@firstname}%        |        |        |
    \else % <-------------------------------------------ELSE--|        |        |
      \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}%                   |        |        |
    \fi % <---------------------------------------------FI---/         |        |
  \else % <------------------------------------------------------ELSE--|        |
    \if@displayvon % <----------------------------------IF---\         |        |
      \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}%         |        |        |
    \else % <-------------------------------------------ELSE--|        |        |
      \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%                    |        |        |
    \fi % <---------------------------------------------FI --/         |        |
  \fi % <--------------------------------------------------------FI---/         |
\fi % <-------------------------------------------------------------------FI---/
```

Your use of a set of closing `\fi`'s doesn't close the groups properly, causing some `\if` clauses to not have a corresponding `\fi` closure.

Answer (score 3):

You have three \if ... The reason why you need also three `\fi`:

```
\if@lastfirstvonname
    \newcommand{\@name}{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}
\else
    \if@vonlastfirstname
        \newcommand{\@name}{\@vonname\ \@lastname,\ \@firstname}
    \else
        \if@firstvonlastname
            \newcommand{\@name}{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
        \else
            \newcommand{\@name}{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
\fi\fi\fi
```

or

```
\if@lastfirstvonname
    \if@displayvon
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}
    \else
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
    \fi
\else
    \if@vonlastfirstname
        \if@displayvon
            \def\@name{\@vonname\ \@lastname,\ \@firstname}
        \else
            \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
        \fi  
    \else
        \if@displayvon
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
        \else
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@lastname}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi
```

Comment: I tried adding a new if inside (see edit) but it does not work when ``\if@displayvon`` is false. Do you know why?

Comment: You need valid blocks, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence of `\if… … \else … \fi` is wrong, e.g., here:

```
\if@lastfirstvonname
    \if@displayvon
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}
    \else
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
\else
```

you have `\if… … \else … \else`, which is not allowed.

So I think, you want something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Name display:
% Include vonname:
\newif\if@displayvon
%\DeclareOption{vonname=true}{\@displayvontrue}
% Displaystyles:
\newif\if@lastfirstvonname
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=lastfirstvon}{\@lastfirstvonnametrue}
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=lastfirst}{\@lastfirstvonnametrue}
\newif\if@vonlastfirstname
%\DeclareOption{namedisplay=vonlastfirst}{\@vonlastfirstnametrue}

\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vonname}[1]{\def\@vonname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}

\if@lastfirstvonname% outer \if… … \else … \fi started
    \if@displayvon% inner \if… … \else … \fi started
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname\ \@vonname}
    \else% else of inner \if… … \else … \fi
        \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
    \fi% inner \if… … \else … \fi finished
\else
    \if@vonlastfirstname% middle \if… … \else … \fi started
        \if@displayvon% inner \if… … \else … \fi started
            \def\@name{\@vonname\ \@lastname,\ \@firstname}
        \else% else of inner \if… … \else … \fi
            \def\@name{\@lastname,\ \@firstname}
        \fi% inner \if…  … \else … \fi finished
    \else% else of middle \if… … \else … \fi
        \if@displayvon% inner \if… … \else … \fi started
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@vonname\ \@lastname}
        \else% else of inner \if… … \else … \fi
            \def\@name{\@firstname\ \@lastname}
        \fi % inner \if… … \else … \fi finished
    \fi % middle \if… … \else … \fi finished
\fi % outer \if… … \else … \fi finished    
\makeatother

\firstname{First}
\vonname{Von}
\lastname{Last}

\begin{document}
hello, my name is \par
\makeatletter
\@name
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

I've commented the parts of all the nested `\if… … \else … \fi`, to make it more clear.